# End of the month and grouping by third month

Tags: sql

I have a question regarding the following SQL code:

```
DECLARE @Date1 datetime
SET @Date1 = DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE());

SELECT
    A.ACCOUNTNUMBER,
    N.FIRST, 
    N.MIDDLE, 
    N.LAST, 
    FORMAT(A.OPENDATE,'MM/dd/yyyy') AS "OPENDATE", 
    FORMAT(A.RECORDCHANGEDATE,'MM/dd/yyyy') AS "LASTMEMBERACTIVITY", 
    L.CHARGEOFFDATE, 
    A.CLOSEDATE, 
    L.CHARGEOFFTYPE, 
    N.EMAIL, 
    N.DEATHDATE
FROM     
    ACCOUNT AS A 
INNER JOIN LOAN AS L ON A.ACCOUNTNUMBER = L.PARENTACCOUNT 
INNER JOIN SAVINGS AS S ON A.ACCOUNTNUMBER = S.PARENTACCOUNT 
INNER JOIN NAME AS N ON A.ACCOUNTNUMBER = N.PARENTACCOUNT
WHERE (L.CHARGEOFFDATE IS NULL) 
  AND (A.CLOSEDATE IS NULL) 
  AND (N.DEATHDATE IS NULL) 
  AND not(N.LAST Like '%Trust%') 
  AND N.EMAIL <> '' 
  AND a.RECORDCHANGEDATE > DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(@Date1, -1)) 
group by             
    A.ACCOUNTNUMBER, 
    N.FIRST, 
    N.MIDDLE, 
    N.LAST, 
    FORMAT(A.OPENDATE,'MM/dd/yyyy'), 
    A.RECORDCHANGEDATE,
    L.CHARGEOFFDATE, 
    A.CLOSEDATE, 
    L.CHARGEOFFTYPE, 
    N.EMAIL, 
    N.DEATHDATE
ORDER BY
    a.RECORDCHANGEDATE desc, DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE());
```

The desired outcome is to show only the month of `05/01/2021` right now it shows August, July, June and May, starting from the first rather than (05/02/2021) that is currently showing.

I have tried the following code and still do not seem to work:

```
SET @startofmonth = DATEADD(dd,1,EOMONTH(@mydate,-1))
SET @startofmonth = DATEADD(dd,1,EOMONTH(Getdate(),-2))
```

Comment: Please add tag of your database and version of database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the error is in your where clause statement where you are comparing

```
a.RECORDCHANGEDATE  > DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(@Date1, -1))
```

you are basically getting all records where a.RECORDCHANGEDATE is greater than (>) `05/01/2021`
if you want all records from MAY month only use one more AND clause

```
AND a.RECORDCHANGEDATE <= EOMONTH(DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(@Date1, -1)))
```